# jquery datepicker select elements displays different in firefox and ie

Tags: css, jquery-plugins, datepicker

After a lot of search and tests, i still can not fix this ui problems.

**1. symptom**

jQuery plugin datepicker display different in firefox and ie.you could view the pic by clicking [FF](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxSXbpgYIZVOZjcwMDNmMmYtMzIyNC00YTdhLTg2MzYtMTJkZGUzNTdhMjdj&hl=en_UShttps://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxSXbpgYIZVOZGZiZTVkOWYtZTRhMy00NzA2LTk0OGYtYTQ2ZmQ2NmUwNTE3&hl=en_US) and [IE](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxSXbpgYIZVOZGZiZTVkOWYtZTRhMy00NzA2LTk0OGYtYTQ2ZmQ2NmUwNTE3&hl=en_US).

You could see that in ie browser the select month and year displays improperly, background color is different in ff, and in FF the datepicker seems more clearly. I don't know why.

**2. css code**
The datePicker you could download at http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html. My code is below,html page is:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @import "datePicker/redmond.datepick.css";
</style>
<span id="calendar" class="datepickHideCalendar">
<p>start date</p><p><input type="text" id="popupDatepickerStart"></p>
<p>end date</p><p><input type="text" id="popupDatepickerEnd"></p>
<table  align="center"><tr><td><button type="button" id="getDates">run</button></td>       </tr></table>
</span>
```

the redmond.datepick.css is as below:

```
    /* Redmond style sheet for jQuery Datepicker v4.0.5. */
@charset "utf-8";
.datepick {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #222;
    border: 1px solid #4297d7;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.25em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-serif;
    font-size: 70%;
}
.datepick-rtl {
    direction: rtl;
}
.datepick-popup {
    z-index: 1000;
}
.datepick-disable {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.datepick a {
    color: #222;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.datepick a.datepick-disabled {
    color: #888;
    cursor: auto;
}
.datepick button {
    margin: 0.25em;
    padding: 0.125em 0em;
    background-color: #5c9ccc;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.25em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.25em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.datepick-nav, .datepick-ctrl {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.datepick-ctrl {
    background-color: #d0e5f5;
}
.datepick-cmd {
    width: 30%;
}
.datepick-cmd:hover {
    background-color: #dfeffc;
}
button.datepick-cmd:hover {
    background-color: #79b7e7;
}
.datepick-cmd-prevJump, .datepick-cmd-nextJump {
    width: 8%;
}
a.datepick-cmd {
    height: 1.5em;
}
button.datepick-cmd {
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-cmd-prev, .datepick-cmd-prevJump, .datepick-cmd-clear {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2%;
}
.datepick-cmd-current, .datepick-cmd-today {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-cmd-next, .datepick-cmd-nextJump, .datepick-cmd-close {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
    text-align: right;
}
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-prev, .datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-prevJump,
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-clear {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 0%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    text-align: right;
}
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-current, .datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-today {
    float: right;
}
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-next, .datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-nextJump,
.datepick-rtl .datepick-cmd-close {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    text-align: left;
}
.datepick-month-nav {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-month-nav div {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 1%;
}
.datepick-month-nav span {
    color: #888;
}
.datepick-month-row {
    clear: left;
}
.datepick-month {
    float: left;
    width: 15em;
    border: 1px solid #5c9ccc;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 90%;
}
.datepick-month-header, .datepick-month-header select, .datepick-month-header input {
    height: 1.7em;
    background-color: #5c9ccc;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.datepick-month-header select, .datepick-month-header input {
    height: 1.7em;
    border: none;
}
.datepick-month-header input {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.datepick-month table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.datepick-month thead {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
}
.datepick-month th, .datepick-month td {
    margin: 0em;
    padding: 0em;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-month th {
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c5dbec;
}
.datepick-month td {
    border: 1px solid #c5dbec;
}
.datepick-month td.datepick-week * {
    background-color: #d0e5f5;
    color: #222;
    border: none;
}
.datepick-month a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.125em 0em;
    background-color: #dfeffc;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.datepick-month span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.125em 0em;
}
.datepick-month td span {
    color: #888;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-other-month {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-today {
    background-color: #fad42e;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-highlight {
    background-color: #79b7e7;
}
.datepick-month td .datepick-selected {
    background-color: #4297d7;
    color: #fff;
}
.datepick-status {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}
.datepick-clear-fix {
    clear: both;
}
.datepick-cover {
    display: none;
    display/**/: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    filter: mask();
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.datepickShowCalendar{visibility:visible}
.datepickHideCalendar{visibility:hidden}
.datePickerTitle{text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold}
.datePickerBtn{font-size:12px}

/* CSS Document */
BODY {
    background-color:#FAFAFA;
}
#calendar{font-size:12px;text-align:center}

TABLE {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    FONT-FAMILY: "微软雅黑", "宋体", "Arial", "Verdana"
}
TD {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    FONT-FAMILY: "微软雅黑", "宋体", "Arial", "Verdana";
}
P {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    FONT-FAMILY: "微软雅黑", "宋体", "Arial", "Verdana";
    color: #003B7F;
}
SELECT {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    FONT-FAMILY: "微软雅黑", "宋体", "Arial", "Verdana"
}
INPUT {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    FONT-FAMILY: "微软雅黑", "宋体", "Arial", "Verdana"
}
TEXTAREA {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    FONT-FAMILY: "微软雅黑", "宋体", "Arial", "Verdana"
}
DIV {
    FONT-SIZE: 12px;
    FONT-FAMILY: "微软雅黑", "宋体", "Arial", "Verdana"
}
TABLE {
    WORD-BREAK: break-all;
    BORDER-COLLAPSE: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
UL {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    MARGIN: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 0px;
    LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none
}
LI {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    MARGIN: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 0px;
    LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none
}
FORM {
    margin:0px;
    LIST-STYLE-TYPE: none
}
FORM {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    MARGIN: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 0px
}
SELECT {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 0px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 0px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 0px;
    MARGIN: 0px;
    PADDING-TOP: 0px
}
A IMG {
    BORDER-RIGHT: 0px;
    BORDER-TOP: 0px;
    BORDER-LEFT: 0px;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px
}
A:link {
color:#000066;
    TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
A:visited {
    TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
A:active {
    TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
A:hover {
    TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
INPUT {
    MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
TEXTAREA {
    VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;
    MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px
}
SELECT {
    VERTICAL-ALIGN:middle;
    MARGIN-RIGHT: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
}

TEXTAREA {
    BORDER: #999999 1px solid;
    PADDING-LEFT: 3px;
    OVERFLOW: auto;
    COLOR: #000;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #fff
}
.datalist_table{
    width:100%;
    border:0px;
}

.datalist_table Th {
    FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
    COLOR: #034579;
    HEIGHT: 26px;
    text-align:left;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:#F0F0F0;
}
.datalist_table TD {

    PADDING-RIGHT: 3px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 3px;
    HEIGHT: 26px;
    TEXT-ALIGN: center;
    color: #003b7f;
}.datalist_table TD {

    PADDING-RIGHT: 3px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 3px;
    HEIGHT: 26px;
    TEXT-ALIGN: center;
    color: #003b7f;
}
.list01 {
    background:#E4EEF3;
}
.list02 {
    background:#D6E4EB
}
```

i want to know which part of the css is wrong? Why IE displays improperly? Thank you guys.

Comment: are you serious? how is this in any way a good use of time? just be happy it even works in IE and focus your attention on more important issues. Getting 100% compatibility between browsers is a fools' errant - you'll never achieve it. Especially when dealing with form elements.

Comment: It affect user experience so i have to fix it! At least i will look almost same.

Comment: I don't agree. It is clear enough in the screenshots - still, it's your time. Be aware though you are trying to style native form elements so the range of supported CSS is limited.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @SpliFF here. It doesn't affect the usability of your application, so don't bother with it until you've fixed all other issues. Sites don't need to look absolutely the same across all the browsers. These kind of minor niggles can be ignored till later. http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/